# Situar botones en vertical html

Tags: html, css

Como podria poner estos botones uno debajo del otro en forma de lista?

un saludo

```html
 <div id="f2c1">
                <button onclick="newBiblioteca()">Nueva Biblioteca</button>
                <button onclick="">Modificar Biblioteca</button>
                <button onclick="">Borrar Biblioteca</button>
                <button onclick="">Buscar Biblioteca</button>
                <button onclick="">Listar Bibliotecas</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: o podrías usar flexBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con una lista.

```html
<div id="f2c1" style="list-style-type:none;">
 <li>
      <ul><button onclick="newBiblioteca()">Nueva Biblioteca</button></ul>
      <ul><button onclick="">Modificar Biblioteca</button></ul>
      <ul><button onclick="">Borrar Biblioteca</button></ul>
      <ul><button onclick="">Buscar Biblioteca</button></ul>
      <ul><button onclick="">Listar Bibliotecas</button></ul>
 </li>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Puedes imaginar que cada botton es un elemento ul en la lista y aplicar `display: block` para que se alineen en bloque(uno debajo de otro);

```css
button {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="f2c1">
  <button onclick="newBiblioteca()">Nueva Biblioteca</button>
  <button onclick="">Modificar Biblioteca</button>
  <button onclick="">Borrar Biblioteca</button>
  <button onclick="">Buscar Biblioteca</button>
  <button onclick="">Listar Bibliotecas</button>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda compañero